# tengo un problema cuando intento ejecutar socialengineering toolkit

Tags: linux, kali-linux

al intentar clonar un sitio web con se-toolkit me aparece este error
Algo salió mal y se imprime el error: el códec 'utf-8' no puede decodificar el byte 0xc3 en la posición 5: byte de continuación no válido
estoy usando el subsistema de linux junto a windows (WSL)